# GMap - onrightclick event not firing if cursor not on top of a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

You can replicate the bug here: http://www.trailbehind.com/node/1148091

For some reason, the following event will fire only if the user's cursor is over a marker, but I have seen it work properly elsewhere, and I'm not sure what's messing things up on my site:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, 'singlerightclick', function(latLng, src, overlay) {
  console.log(1);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Please edit the title: it's non-descriptive and presumptuous...

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right, and when I visit the URL you give (I've tried only with Google Chrome) and right-click at any spot, a marker appears with relevant information. What misbehavior am I supposed to observe (or fail to observe) and on what browser?

Comment: Works just fine here as well.

Comment: Works with Chrome, Firefox, IE6/7/8. Fails in Opera - but that's expected because Opera doesn't allow scripts to receive right clicks.

Comment: I just confirmed it also works with Safari on my Mac. @Andrew, can you at all clarify the issue...?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in firefox on Mac.
See details here -
    http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1545

I hope there is a solution soon.